# PyCharm requirements.txt warning says packages are not installed, but they *are* installed

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm getting this error for all of my packages in my `requirements.txt`:

```
'<PackageName> X.Y.Z' is not installed (required: X.Y.Z, installed: <nothing>, latest: X.Y.Z)
```

But when I open up the virtual environment settings, I can see that all of those packages are, in fact, installed into the virtual environment.

How do I resolve this?

[image]

[image]